# Is there any way to get menu button on Android when the min and target SDK versions are 14?

Tags: android

I have menu button in my application. My application had a targetSDK version as 8 and I am planning to change it to 14.  In API level 14, menu button is removed.  So, I couldn't see menu button when I changed the target SDK to 14.  Is there any way to display the menu button while keeping the target SDK to 14?

Comment: The menu button is showing up as an action overflow button in the title bar.  I couldn't see that earlier as my title bar was disabled in my application because of the application level theme :   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black"  This theme when set, is disabling the title bars for all the application's activities.  Note: I don't have action bar in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old "menu button" is now the overflow in your action bar, or is triggered by an off-screen MENU button on the device. No devices that ship originally with Android 4.4 or higher will have a MENU button.

> Is there any way to display the menu button while keeping the target SDK to 14?

No. It should already be accessible via your action bar. If you do not have an action bar, you need to implement your own menu system that is part of your own UI.